# Count variation while merging the two dataframes in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to update the DOB and gender details in my subtable(1797655 rows) from the master df(793145 rows) using matched IDs.

`df1` - (Sub-table)

```
 ID
    123
    123
    122
    122
    124
    124
    121
    121
```

`df2` - (Master-table)

```
ID  DOB         SEX
123 22-04-1996  M
122 16-06-1994  M
124 25-05-1990  F
121 13-12-1993  F
…
```

I used the below code to update those two columns.

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by="ID",all.x = TRUE)
```

It successfully updated the DOB and gender but additionally 266 rows added in the sub-table why? (i.e after the merge code the sub table row count became 1797921.   (1797921 - 1797655 = 266))
I checked the additional rows in terms of duplicates (50 rows removed), I'm unable to find the remaining  216 rows in the data.

Kindly suggest a code/alternative method to solve the problem
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have duplicates `ID`s in `df2`.

Look at the example below:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(123,123,122,122,124,124,121,121))
df2 <- read.table(text = "ID  DOB         SEX
                          123 22-04-1996  M
                          122 16-06-1994  M
                          124 25-05-1990  F
                          121 13-12-1993  F",
                          header = TRUE)


left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>% nrow
#> 8



df2 <- read.table(text = "ID  DOB         SEX
                          123 22-04-1996  M
                          123 22-04-1996  F
                          122 16-06-1994  M
                          124 25-05-1990  F
                          121 13-12-1993  F",
                          header = TRUE)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>% nrow
#> 10
```

Duplicates in `df1` don't matter.

Do this to find duplicates in `df2`:

```
df2 %>%
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n()>1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

You need to decide which one is the right one. Maybe there is a mistake in the data preparation..?

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for your concern I have tried your suggested methods and resulted in same increased duplicates. Yes there is duplicates in both the data frames but i need only my sub table to be updated from the master table but i face increased count and duplicates. Help me out with another way

Comment: As I said, you need to figure out why you have duplicates in the master table and you need to decide how to rule out the duplicates in the master table (i.e. always keep the most recent..?).Remove the duplicates from the master table and then your join will go as expected.

Comment: Thanks dude it worked perfectly as you said I got exact row count

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicates from `df1`. Try :

```
df3 <- merge(unique(df1), df2, by= 'ID', all.x = TRUE)
```

When you have duplicates in the `df1` they create rows with all the rows of the same `ID` in `df2` which drastically increases the number of rows in the final data.

In `dplyr`, you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% left_join(df2, by = 'ID')
```

---

After discussion with @Edo, I think there could also be cases where there can be duplicates in `df1` as well as `df2` in which case, you can take `distinct` rows from both the dataframes before joining them.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
        distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
        left_join(df2 %>% 
                  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE), by = 'ID')
```

Comment: Even if there are duplicates in `df1` he should still get the same number of rows at the end (since `df1` is the `left` dataframe). The problem should be related to duplicates `ID`s in `df2`

Comment: I think duplicates in any of the dataframe can result in increased number of rows.

Comment: No duplicates: `df1<-data.frame(a=1:4);df2<-data.frame(a=1:4);nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a'))==nrow(df1)#TRUE`
Duplicates in df1: `df1<-data.frame(a=c(1:4, 1));df2<-data.frame(a=1:4);nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a'))==nrow(df1)#TRUE`
Duplicates in df2: `df1<-data.frame(a=1:4);df2<-data.frame(a=c(1:4,1)):nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a'))==nrow(df1)#FALSE`

Comment: Duplicates in `df1` and `df2`: `df1<-data.frame(a=c(1:4, 1));
df2<-data.frame(a=c(1:4, 1));nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a')) == nrow(df2) #FALSE`. So duplicates can be present in both the dataframes.

Comment: My previous comment was slightly imprecise. To be more specific, since the question is about a left join: `df1<-data.frame(a=1:4);df2<-data.frame(a=1:4);nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a',all.x=TRUE))==nrow(df1)#TRUE`
`df1<-data.frame(a=c(1:4, 1));df2<-data.frame(a=1:4);nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a',all.x=TRUE))==nrow(df1)#TRUE`
`df1<-data.frame(a=1:4);df2<-data.frame(a=c(1:4,1));nrow(merge(df1,df2,by='a',all.x=TRUE))==nrow(df1)#FALSE`. Thus, if our goal is to keep the same number of rows for `df1`, the problem must be related to `df2`